# missing module when deploy nodejs application to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I tried to deploy my app to heroku, I kept getting this error in the log

```
2022-05-20T14:49:35.602605+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2022-05-20T14:49:35.602605+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719423+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719424+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719425+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719428+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719428+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'csv-parse'
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719428+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719429+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719431+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719431+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719431+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719432+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:6:15)
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719432+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
2022-05-20T14:49:35.719432+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)

2022-05-20T15:08:40.259973+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259974+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259974+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259974+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259974+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259975+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:5:17)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259975+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259975+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259975+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
2022-05-20T15:08:40.259976+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
```

I am pretty sure the node.js application can successfully run locally and I have installed all the necessary packages in `dependencies` inside package.json. Not sure how to fix it....

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Netflix User Study Framework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Encode username into prolific id",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.3"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/amyhua/basic-website-template-node.git"
  },
  "author": "YOUR NAME GOES HERE",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/amyhua/basic-website-template-node/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/amyhua/basic-website-template-node#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1139.0",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "csv-stringify": "^6.0.5",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "generate-unique-id": "^2.0.1",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "os": "^0.1.2"
  }
}
```

Also, I set up a .env file with PORT # on 3000.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your package.json?

Comment: No problem. Just updated!

Comment: Well, this one is beyond my ability to debug with the available information as I haven't used heroku in several years. As an aside I would recommend updating your node version, v12 just went end of life and you're showing 8.9.